# Enable disk option for rtcwake

Tags: hibernate, hibernation

I was trying to use `rtcwake` to put the laptop to sleep via the disk but the `disk` option is not available.

Is it a misconfiguration or it's not supported at all by my laptop? How can I investigate this and ideally enable the disk option?

```
$ sudo rtcwake -u -s 60 -m disk
rtcwake: unrecognized suspend state 'disk'

$ cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem
```

Thank you

Comment: Run `rtcwake --list-modes` to get a list of valid modes.

Comment: @vidarlo It returns `freeze mem off no on disable show` but I don't understand why the disk option is not present.